# Cant find Apple Watch template in xcode 6.2

Tags: xcode, ios8, apple-watch

I have just downloaded xcode 6.2 to work on apple watch sdk. but i cant find template for apple watch .

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no template for Apple Watch, it is a target instead. So create your app (or open an existing one), select a project and add a new target. You are going to see an Apple Watch extension.

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That shows in new->Project.
I just created new target and it shows in that tab..
New->Target->AppleWatch